# Error calling on .hpp functions into main code

Tags: c++, xcode, function

I am working on a basic DAW for university. I have all the functions working however I want to place them all in separate functions and call on them in the main function. I am getting the error of expression result unused. Any help would be appreciated. First block is my main function.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
extern "C"
{
#include <sndfile.h>
}
using namespace std;
#include "LoadFile.hpp"
#include "SaveFile.hpp"
#include "Amplify.hpp"
#include "Delay.hpp"
#include "Distortion.hpp"
#include "FadeIn.hpp"




int main ()

{

    int choice;

    cout << "What would you like to do? \n 1. Load File \n 2. Save File \n 3. Amplify \n 4. Fade In \n 5. Distortion \n 6. Delay \n 7. Close Program \n";
    cin >> choice;

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        LoadFile;
    }

    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        SaveFile;
    }

    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        Amplify;
    }

    else if (choice == 4)
    {
        FadeIn;
    }

    else if (choice == 5)
    {
        Distortion;
    }
    else if (choice == 6)
    {
        Delay;
    }

    else if (choice == 7)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Sorry, that isn't an option";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

These are a couple of my .cpp and .hpp files.

```
#include "SaveFile.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
extern "C"
{
#include <sndfile.h>
}
using namespace std;
#include "LoadFile.hpp"


void SaveFile (double *x, int length)
{
    int samplerate2;

    cout << "Please enter save path. \n";
    string strSPath2;
    cin >> strSPath2;
    const char *SPath2 = strSPath2.c_str();
    cout << "Enter samplerate. \n";
    cin >> samplerate2;

    SF_INFO FInfo2;
    FInfo2.format = SF_FORMAT_WAV | SF_FORMAT_PCM_16;
    FInfo2.samplerate = samplerate2;
    FInfo2.channels = 1;
    SNDFILE *SFile2 = sf_open(SPath2, SFM_WRITE, &FInfo2);
    sf_writef_double(SFile2, x, length);
    sf_write_sync(SFile2);
    sf_close(SFile2);
    cout << "Save successful \n";


    delete [] x;
}
```

Corresponding .hpp.

```
void SaveFile(double *x, int length);
```

Comment: Please provide exact error compiler shows. Possibly also mentioning what compiler it is and with what options.

Comment: First that hits me is that your `main` doesn't appear to call intended functions. You are only mentioning names of functions, which probably works as taking their addresses and since you don't assign them to anything it is an unused expression. As you showed yourself with the `SaveFile` there are arguments to be provided to the function. So `main` must provide those arguments.

Comment: The code builds correctly but when an option is chosen it closes. It says next to each function 'Expression result unused'.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're calling functions inappropriately.

You call a function like this: `LoadFile` ...
whereas you should call it like this: `LoadFile()` ...

You need to pass your parameters into these functions from main.
E.g if you want to call `SaveFile()`, you need to pass in the appropriate parameters. Using your `SaveFile()` hpp definition, you need to pass in `double *x` and `int length` into `SaveFile()` to call it properly.

I suspect you will need to do the same with your other functions you have in main as well.